# seaborn barplot "Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

So am working on telecommunication dataset to create a machine learning model to predict the churn rate.
When I started to create barplots I get a type error which says "Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric".
Both x and y variables are dtype= object

My question is when creating such plots is it compulsory any one variable should be numeric? I tried to google the reason but was unable to understand, If any can help me with a proper explanation it would be great.

Comment: Can you provide some insight into the structure of your data? What kind of data do x and y store?

Comment: X and Y are currently storing categorical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boxplot graphically depicts the distribution of **numerical** data through quartiles. So yes, at least one of the variables has to be numeric. You cannot describe a distribution or quartiles for a categorical variable (What would be its mean value? What would be its max or min value?)

Also check the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) on how categorical data is treated:

> A box plot (or box-and-whisker plot) shows the distribution of quantitative data
> (...) This function always treats one of the variables as categorical (...)

Also check the examples in the documentation. They are pretty helpful.

Your x and y variables are both categorical. Is one of them numbers saved as strings? In that case, transform this array to a numerical type (float or int depending on your data) and the boxplot should work.